# Mapping a bunch of hashes in Perl, but its skipping a single value in the mapping?

Tags: perl, hash, dictionary

This will be a lot easier to show in code than explain. I've just got a hash mapping to quickly fill a hash to run replacements on data the script reads in. E.g. if 5 output 6, if 3 output 2, if 23 output 6, etc etc. This works pretty well except for not mapping one of the keys.

(btw, if anyone can think of a more elegant way to map several keys in a hash to a single value, let me know :) )

Anyways onto the code...

```
$COLUMN = 6;

%PERIOD_1 = (map {(  1, 10, 14, 20, 22, 29, 35, 39 )[$_] => 1 } 0..100); #1st period
%PERIOD_2 = (map {(  3, 8, 11, 18, 24, 26, 32, 37  )[$_] => 2 } 0..100); #2nd period
%PERIOD_3 = (map {(  7, 13, 16, 21, 28, 34, 36     )[$_] => 3 } 0..100); #3rd period
%PERIOD_4 = (map {(  5, 2, 6, 15, 17, 23, 27, 31,38)[$_] => 4 } 0..100); #4th period
%PERIOD_5 = (map {(  4, 9, 12, 19, 25, 30, 33, 40  )[$_] => 5 } 0..100); #5th period

%PERIODS = (%PERIOD_1,%PERIOD_2,%PERIOD_3,%PERIOD_4,%PERIOD_5);

open (FILE,"<",$ARGV[0]);

while(<FILE>) {
   my @columns = split(/\t/);
   print $columns[$COLUMN] . "-" . $PERIODS{$columns[$COLUMN]};
} 

close(FILE);
```

So this works pretty well. You get an output like:

```
37-2
29-1
15-4
6-4
34-3
24-2
5-
```

Which matches/replaces literally every value **EXCEPT 5**. I don't get it - all of the other keys in the mapping are in the hash, but for some reason 5 (and only 5) isn't. Could someone explain wtf the problem is? edit: fixed formatting

EDIT: **YES, I USED WARNINGS IN THE CODE.** I really don't care about the warning though (even if it is related to my problem) - I just want the problem solved. If I cared to understand the warning I would've asked about it.

Comment: Why do you think a subscript on a list in parenthesis is a good idea? For most of those indexes, you will get no value, because your lists are all shorter than about 10 numbers, so index 11 .. 100 are unused, and only results in a long row of 1's.

Comment: You are not calling `chomp` on your input. The last element of `@columns` probably has a newline character.

Comment: mob - I deleted chomp because it's irrelevant - my real code has it.
TLP - this script is only running on a 2kb file once a week, so speed/memory consumption isn't really a concern. 100 was a nice arbitrary number, as the lists could exceed 10 numbers.

@toolic - Interesting...but I don't get why that matters?:S Is there not a way to do this with an odd number of hash keys you want to map??

Comment: @user891876 "Odd number of elements in hash assignment" does not refer to the number of keys, but of the number of keys *and* values. The total number of elements in a hash assignment must be even, not odd, because that means that some key has no value.

Answer (score 3):

This is some rather unusual code, and its probably not doing what you think. For example:

```
%PERIOD_2 = (map {(  3, 8, 11, 18, 24, 26, 32, 37  )[$_] => 2 } 0..100);
```

This will iterate over numbers from 0 to 100, but only 0 to 7 are of any interest to you, since the list contains 8 numbers. The subscript for 8, for example, will be empty, and the map iteration will return `() => 2`, or just a single 2. This will mean that you will get a long string of `2,2,2,2,2,2,2`, which will lead to the key `2` always existing in that hash, no matter if it is in the list or not.

This is an overly complicated way of turning a list into a hash. You would normally just do:

```
my %hash = map { $_ => 2 } (  3, 8, 11, 18, 24, 26, 32, 37 );
```

And if you had several lists to merge into one hash, you would do

```
my %hash;
for my $num (1, 10, 14, 20, 22, 29, 35, 39) {
    $hash{$num} = 1;
}
for my $num (3, 8, 11, 18, 24, 26, 32, 37) {
    $hash{$num} = 2;
}
....
```

If you had used

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

You would most likely not have this problem, because you would get the warning `Odd number of elements in hash assignment` as [toolic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/197758/toolic) pointed out.

Also, in cases such as these, using the [`Data::Dumper`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::Dumper) module to debug is very convenient:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \%hash;   # send ref to hashes and arrays
```

For the code you had above, with these debugging tools you would get this output:

```
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at foo.pl line 9.
$VAR1 = {
          '32' => 2,
          '11' => 2,
          '3' => 2,
          '26' => 2,
          '2' => undef,
          '8' => 2,
          '18' => 2,
          '24' => 2,
          '37' => 2
        };
```

And as you can see, the problem is immediately identifiable: The key `2` has no value.

When you add the hashes together, you also overwrite previous valid values, such as the one for `5`. For example:

```
%hash1 = (5 => 2);
%hash2 = (5 => undef);
%hash  = (%hash1, %hash2);
```

Since hash keys are unique, `5 => undef` will overwrite `5 => 2`.

The `"Odd number of elements"` warning refers to the list that is assigned to the hash, not the number of keys. For example:

```
my %foo = (1, 2, 3);  # odd number of elements
```

This hash will now have the keys `1` and `3`, but key `3` will not have a value, so it will be `undef`. Usually in hash assignment, you want an even number of elements, so that each key has a value.

Comment: lol I knew exactly what it was doing - I didn't like it any better than you, but I couldn't figure out the "elegant" way of doing it.

I used warnings in the code, I just ignored it because it seemed like a stupid warning. I knew there was an odd number of elements in the hash assignment - that's what I wanted...I'm still not too sure why that's an issue.

thanks though! this is just what i needed

Comment: @user891876, it's an issue because a hash assignment should be a list of key-value pairs (i.e. always an even number of elements).  If it's odd, the last key gets the value `undef`.  That's normally a mistake, so you get a warning.  If you really meant that, then just use an explicit `undef` to avoid the warning.

Comment: @user891876 Warnings in Perl are always important in one way or another, they can always be avoided with the proper code, and its almost always important to know why a warning is issued.

Comment: I'm not a perl programmer - I could care less about why the warning was issued. I just want the code to work.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. Apparently you should have cared why the warning was issued. There is a connection between knowing what you are doing and producing code that works.

Answer (score 2):

You should *always*

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

at the top of your programs, and declare every variable with `my` as close as possible to its first point of use.

You should also preferably use only lower case and underscore for your variable names. Upper case is reserved for global identifiers like package names.

It is best to use a lexical file handle instead of a global one, and you should *always* check the success of your `open` calls, dying with the value of `$!` in the `die` string. Like this

```
open my $file, '<', $ARGV[0] or die "Unable to open input file: $!";
```

What this will do

```
my %period = (map {(  1, 10, 14, 20, 22, 29, 35, 39 )[$_] => 1 } 0..100);
```

is correctly generate your key/value pairs for those elements in the list, but when you get to 8 (the size of the list) it will just produce the value `1` as there is no corresponding element of the list. So you get

```
 1 => 1,
10 => 1,
14 => 1,
20 => 1,
22 => 1,
29 => 1,
35 => 1,
39 => 1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
1,
```

and for those hashes where there is an even number of elements in the list you will end up with an unpaired trailing value.

I suggest you put the information into a data file, or at least into the `__DATA__` section of your program, and read it into the hash like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $column = 6;

my %periods;
while (<DATA>) {
  my ($val, @keys) = /\d+/g;
  next unless $val;
  $periods{$_} = $val for @keys;
}

open my $fh, "<", $ARGV[0];

while(<$fh>) {
  my @columns = split /\t/;
  my $key = $columns[$column];
  printf "%s - %s\n", $key, $periods{$key};
} 

__DATA__
1:  1, 10, 14, 20, 22, 29, 35, 39;
2:  3,  8, 11, 18, 24, 26, 32, 37;
3:  7, 13, 16, 21, 28, 34, 36;
4:  5,  2,  6, 15, 17, 23, 27, 31, 38;
5:  4,  9, 12, 19, 25, 30, 33, 40;
```

(Don't worry about the format of the lines after `__DATA__`. It takes notice only of the decimal digits in the line. Everything else is just layout and is ignored.)

Comment: @amon: Yeah thanks. I moved what I was going to write earlier in the post. Fixed.

Comment: You should *always* `use strict` as well. You won't get much sympathy from others if you need help with problems but refuse to use it. *"These don't need to be maintained by anyone"* until you can't get your code working and need to ask for help, for instance on Stack Overflow.

Comment: To get `use strict` to work, most often you just need to declare your variables, e.g. `my $foo`. There is a short learning curve to using warnings and strict, and in the long run, they will end up saving you much more time than you spent learning how to use them.